# Select lines based on value in a column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tab delimited table for which I want to print all lines where column 'x' is greater than 'Y'. I have attempted using the code below but am new to using awk so am unsure how to use it based on columns.

```
awk '$X >= Y {print} ' Table.txt | cat > Wanted_lines
```

Y are values from 1 to 100.

If the input were like below with column X were the second column.

```
1    30
2    50
3    100
4    100
5    80
6    79
7    90
```

The wanted output would be:

```
3    100
4    100
5    80
7    90
```

The first 2 lines of the file is:

```
1   OTU1    243622  208679  121420  265864  0   0   2   0   0   11  1   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   839604  OTU1    -   Archaea 100%    Euryarchaeota   100%    Methanobacteria 100%    Methanobacteriales  100%    Methanobacteriaceae 100%    Methanobrevibacter  100%
2   OTU2    84366   120817  15834   74737   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   295755  OTU2    -   Archaea 100%    Euryarchaeota   100%    Methanobacteria 100%    Methanobacteriales  100%    Methanobacteriaceae 100%    Methanobrevibacter  100%
```

Comment: What are "X" and "Y"? (Can you post some sample input and desired output?)

Comment: Ok updated the explanation so more detail is given.

Comment: Updated answer fo yopur actual file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First**

awk's default internal field separator (FS) will work on space or tab delimited files.

**Secondly**

```
awk '$x > FLOOR' Table.txt
```

Where `$x` is the target column, and `FLOOR` is the actual numeric floor (i.e. 5000, etc ...)

Example file: awktest

```
500  100
400  1100
1000 400
1200 500


awk '$1 > 1000' awktest

1200   500

awk '$1 >= 1000' awktest

1000   400 
1200   500
```

Thus, you should be able to use a relational expression to print the lines where x > y, in the form:

```
awk '$x > $y' awktest
```

Where `$x` is a numeric column as in `$1`, or other.

Where `$y` is a numeric column as in `$2`, or other.

**Example**:

```
awk '$1 > $2' awktest
```

or ...

```
awk '$2 > $1' awktest
```

awk numbers are floating point numbers, so you can compare decimals, too.

Comment: I meant for X to be the specific column I want the numbers for comparison to be taken from and Y is the limit for which I only want numbers great than to be taken.

Comment: I see. I made my change. Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by 'actual numeric floor', would this be the value I want to be the selection value e.g if FLOOR were 80, all numbers above 80 would be kept?

Comment: Yes. Simply substitute the number 80 where the word FLOOR appears above. Crude, but efficient. :-) I tried this myself and it works.

Comment: +1, though in this case I think it would be better to choose example values for `x` and `FLOOR` so you can post an actual working example.

Comment: Good idea. I think I will.

Comment: Given the way the question is worded, one might assume that `X` and `Y` might vary. While the OP's immediate needs are met, it might be useful for posterity to include an example that uses awk's `-v` option to utilize non-static values.

Comment: @ghoti That would not help the OP. However, the new examples would. A good book or man page can inform someone about the `-v` option for specifying a variable to an awk command. In this situation, it would be surplus to requirement.

Comment: It might, but we write answers both for the OP and for future readers who may find solutions to their own problems. And I guarantee you that future readers will be able to contribute more to your score than the OP's 25 points. :)

Comment: @ghoti It cannot hurt to mention the `-v` option, but without an example, the usefulness of mentioning it is almost nil. Using the `-v` option to insert a variable into an awk command, or script may be a good solution in some circumstances, but not here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk -v num_col=$X -v limit=$Y '$num_col + 0 >= limit + 0' Table.txt > Wanted_lines
```

Example:

```
$ cat Table.txt
1    30
2    50
3    100
4    100
5    80
6    79
7    90


$ X=2
$ Y=80
$ awk -v num_col=$X -v limit=$Y '$num_col + 0 > limit + 0' Table.txt
3    100
4    100
5    80
7    90
```

Alternatively (hacky and **NOT recomended**) awk enclosure could be broken this way:

```
$  awk '$'"${X}"' + 0 >= '"${Y}"' + 0' Table.txt
```

This is what you need to get rid of **%** symbol in your actual file:

```
$ awk -v num_col=43 -v limit=80 '{sub(/%/,"",$num_col)}$num_col + 0 >= limit + 0 ' Table.txt
```

Comment: This seems to create the Wanted_lines file but is empty although I know many of the lines have values greater than Y in column X

Comment: Post a piece of your file and values parsed

Comment: Ok added the first 2 lines of my actual file now.

Comment: Ok, column to analyze an value ?

Comment: Realised that I had been stating the wrong column, however even when using the correct column only 26 lines were selected and only a few of those in the output file actually had a value over 80.

Comment: Also the column is 43

Comment: The exact code I used was awk -v num_col=$43 -v limit=$80 '$num_col + 0 > limit' OTU_Mega_tred.txt > Wanted_lines

Comment: Ok , i see the problem .. sign % in the actual value .. i will update the post

Comment: That seems to have worked however in halfing the number of rows as wanted but all the data is now in a single column so the output it like this: 1 OTU1 243622 208679 121420 265864 0 0 2 0 0 11 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 839604 OTU1 - Archaea 100% Euryarchaeota 100% Methanobacteria 100% Methanobacteriales 100% Methanobacteriaceae 100 Methanobrevibacter 100%
2 OTU2 84366 120817 15834 74737 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 295755 OTU2 - Archaea 100% Euryarchaeota 100% Methanobacteria 100% Methanobacteriales 100% Methanobacteriaceae 100 Methanobrevibacter 100%

Comment: I have used tr '%' ' ' <OTU_Mega_tred.txt> OTU_now to remove the % sign that was causing the issue and then used your original code however all the lines were selected and moved to the output file

Comment: Works fine for me , but try '$num_col + 0 >= limit + 0{print $0"\n"}' to add an extra rc

Comment: Ok I have just used the line : 
$ awk -v num_col=43 -v limit=80 '{sub(/%/,"",$num_col)}$num_col + 0 >= limit + 0{print $0"\n"}' Table.txt
 and the same issue occured where all the detail is put into a single column. I am opening up the files with excel to check their format.

Answer (score 0):

So...

- `'$X >= Y {print}'` is redundant, as the default action in awk is to print.
- `| cat > file` is [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)).
- Your expected output shows lines where that value is 80 or above. This answer assumes the output is what you really want, despite the lack of code to handle it.
- I don't see how your last input example relates to things. Is there particular output you'd like from that input?

Consider:

```
$ awk '$X >= Y' X=2 Y=80 input.txt
3    100
4    100
5    80
7    90
$ awk '$X >= Y' X=2 Y=90 input.txt
3    100
4    100
7    90
```

The notation above relies on the following statement from `man awk`:

> Any file of the form var=value
>         is treated as an assignment, not a filename, and  is  executed  at  the
>         time  it  would  have been opened if it were a filename.

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
$ awk -v X=2 -v Y=80 '$X >= Y' input.txt
```

Either of these notations for getting shell variables into your awk script will do just fine, I believe any version of awk you come across (bsdawk, gawk, mawk) should handle both equally well.

Within a shell script, you might see something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
  printf 'Please supply column and floor values as parameters.\n'
  exit 1
elif [[ $1 =~ [^0-9] ]] || [[ $2 =~ [^0-9] ]]; then
  printf 'Invalid parameters.\n'
  exit 1
fi

awk '$X >= Y' X="$1" Y="$2" input.txt
```